# Terms Prevalence in SolR searches

Tags: solr

Is there a way to specify a set of terms that are more important when performing a search?

For example, in the following question:

"This morning my printer ran out of paper"

Terms such as "printer" or "paper" are far more important than the rest, and I don't know if there is a way to list these terms to indicate that, in the global knowledge, they'd have more weight than the rest of words.

Answer (score 1):

For specific documents you can use [QueryElevationComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent), which uses special XML file in which you place your specific terms for which you want specific doc ids.
Not exactly what you need, I know.

And regarding your comment about users not caring what's underneath, you control the final query. Or, in the worst case, you can modify it after you receive it at Solr server side.

Similar: [Lucene term boosting with sunspot-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186844/lucene-term-boosting-with-sunspot-rails)

Answer (score 0):

When you build the query you can define what are the values and how much these fields have weight on the search.
This can be done in many ways:

1. Setting the boost

   The boost can be set by using `"^ "`
2. Using plus operator
   If you define + operator in your query, if there is a exact result for that filed value it is shown in the result.

For a better understanding of solr, it is best to get familiar with lucene query syntax. Refer to this [link to get more info](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html).

Comment: Hi @RJ45, you're right but what I'm trying to develop is a system where the user doesn't have to know which is the notation underlying.
I've thought about executing a pre-processing phase for marking for boost the terms I want to but I don't know if there's another way.

Comment: When you build your index you can set the weight manually. By this way you can improve your searching ability. And one another impotent thing is scoring. You can get the your score of the query and use that to filter the value of searching. These are the things that I found so far. I'm also developing an application and faced the similar problem :)